# Независимое прибавление/уменьшение значения при нажатии на кнопки, для нескольких карточек

Tags: javascript, html, input, button

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы имея несколько карточек, при нажатии на "**+**" или "**-**" менялось значение `<input>`, но на каждой карточке кнопка отвечала бы за свой `<input>`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал код, чтобы на одной карточке это работало, но если перебирать, то будет работать для всех `<input>`.

```js
let plus = document.querySelector("#plus");
let minus = document.querySelector("#minus");
let input = document.querySelector("#count");

plus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  input.value++;
  input.innerHTML = input.value;
});
minus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  input.value--;
  input.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

```html
<button class="counter-button" id="minus">-</button>
<input class="counter-input" id="count" type="text" value="1">
<button class="counter-button" id="plus">+</button>
```

В общем, я не знаю, что изучить для этого или как дальше действовать. Решение ищу на JS. Спасибо.

Comment: Неужели скриншот сделать легче, чем скопировать и вставить код?

Comment: кажется тут студенты подъехали с лабораторками))) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1243145/191482

Comment: @UModeL, виноват , изменил

Comment: @Schwarzrus на самом деле в ссылке, что я написал в комментарии написано всё что нужно делать. Там есть и ответ тоже, но если вы хотите научиться чему-то, то лучше почитать комменты, вникнуть и сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ,благодарю за наводку ,очень много перерыл и всё в основном на Jquery , а хочется понять на самом Js

Comment: @Schwarzrus там оно и есть. Там ни капли Jquery

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я имел ввиду , что вообще ,когда искал .Очень помогли ссылкой , ещё раз спасибо